# What's the difference between zip and list in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, zip

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6]
for x,y in list(zip(a,b)):
    if y==5:
        b.remove(y)
        continue
    else:
        print(x,y)

output: 2 6
```

but the following code output nothing.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6]
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    if y==5:
        b.remove(y)
        continue
    else:
        print(x,y)
```

so, why this happend? please help,thanks!

Comment: `list` creates a new list that has no connection to the `zip` iterator and the underlying lists. Without it, you modify `b` on the first iteration, which the zip iterator is using, and then you see the classic bug of modifying/removing from a list while iterating over it, shifting all the indices and skipping the next element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying list `b` in your loop, which in turn terminates the loop over `zip(a,b)` prematurely as you have removed an element. The reason it works to wrap it in a `list()` is that you have effectively copied the structure you get from `zip()`, so when you remove an element from `b`, that leaves the `list(zip(a,b))` unchanged as it has already been created. So even though you remove `6` from `b`, you still have the pair `2,6` in the list you made from the zip.

Answer (score 1):

## Here's what going on.

By modifying the original lists (`a` and `b`) with calls like `b.remove(...)`, you actually mess with the way your `zip` spits out values.

- `zip(a, b)` returns an *iterator*, which doesn't actually store its data. Instead, it just stores *how to get it's data*.
- more info on zip [here](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/)